# CSS: unorderred list <ul> Indent issue in IE

Tags: css

I have an issue with unorderred list tag () when run it in IE.

Please review this link with IE and Chrome. Currently, my  bullet overlaps my image. How could I fix this in IE?

http://jsfiddle.net/5yygs2ud/4/

```
<div class="wysiwyg">
<div style="float: left; margin: 0 12px 8px 0;">
    <img src="" alt="" width="267" height="200" style="background-color:yellow"/>
</div>


 <p><strong>My title!</strong></p>
<ol>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3 </li>
</ul>
My content!
</div>
```

and CSS is:

```
.wysiwyg ol {
list-style-position: inside;
```

}

NOTE: Ideally, I dont want to move text stuff outside 'div.wysiwug'. You can create new div to wrap it or move it into above image div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying your CSS for the ol to the ul as well did the trick.  I also wrapped your right hand content in a div for cleanliness sake

```
.wysiwyg ol, .wysiwyg ul {
     list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/5yygs2ud/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wysiwyg">
<div style="float: left; margin: 0 12px 8px 0;">
    <img src="" alt="" width="267" height="200"/>
</div>      
    <p><strong>My title!</strong></p>
    <ol>
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Line 2</li>
        <li>Line 3</li>
    </ol>
    <ul>
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Line 2</li>
        <li>Line 3 </li>
    </ul>
    My content!

    please add ol and ul this property in css:
    ol,
    ul{display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works. But above answer is better, I think :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add `display property` `value` of `block` to the `LI`, you'll be just fine.

```css
li {
   
    display: block;
}

.wysiwyg ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="wysiwyg">
 <div style="float: left; margin: 0 12px 8px 0;">
        <img src="" alt="" width="267" height="200" style="background-color:yellow"/>
 </div>

        

     <p><strong>My title!</strong></p>
<ol>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3 </li>
</ul>
My content!
</div>
```